# Stopping NSTimer with UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nstimer

I have implemented some code that allows a user to set a time limit to countdown from using UIDatePicker, the users then presses a "Start" button and the countdown is printed in to a UILabel.

I am trying to find a way to stop the timer. Here is the code I have so far that starts the timer:

```
@implementation P11DetailController
int afterRemainder;
int iRemainder;
NSTimeInterval countDownInterval;

- (void)updateCountDown{
afterRemainder --;

int hours = (int)(afterRemainder)/(60*60);
int mins = (int)(((int)afterRemainder/60) - (hours * 60));
int secs = (int)(((int)afterRemainder - (60 * mins) - ( 60*hours*60)));

NSString *displayText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02u : %02u :
%02u", hours, mins, secs];

self.displayLabel.text = displayText;
}
```

then when the user user presses "start":

```
- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender {
countDownInterval = (NSTimeInterval)_countdownTimer.countDownDuration;
iRemainder = countDownInterval;
afterRemainder = countDownInterval - iRemainder%60;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self 
selector:@selector(updateCountDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

}

and finally, when the users presses "Stop":

```
- (IBAction)stopButton:(id)sender {
//not sure what to add here

}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to `NSTimer` as an ivar:

```
@implementation P11DetailController
{
NSTimer *myTimer;
}
```

then:

`myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self 
selector:@selector(updateCountDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

Then a simple call to:

`[myTimer invalidate];`

Will stop the timer.

This is all in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/) which you should consult first.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Furthermore, when my timer reaches zero, it doesn't stop, it goes to something like 00 : 00 : 429474924928 and keeps on counting down. Is there a way to stop the timer when it hits 00 : 00 : 00 with my current code?

Comment: I have managed to achieve this using an if statement to check whether the values are 0 and invalidate the timer.